# Is there a way to use @Autowired at once in all repository files?

Tags: spring, spring-data-jpa

first, i'm sorry because it is not technical question.

just i need simply code to use all repository.

my example code:

```java
public class somethingTest {
    @Autowired private repositoryA repoA;
    @Autowired private repositoryB repoB;
    @Autowired private repositoryC repoC;
    @Autowired private repositoryD repoD;
    ...
}
```

i think if i got about 20 repositories, then i write 20 line for something test.

my body and hand refuse it :(

do you have any idea to writing simply code than above??

Comment: No. If you need it, you have to declare it. If that's a problem you can always have someone else do it.

Comment: This **is** the simple code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Abstraction. Try to create a service that is responsible for a smaller piece of functionality. If you try to add 5 repo for a single service most probably you are doing it wrong. Think again why you need all these repositories. After you create smaller units you will have to include less repository and your tests will also better to write and understand